# How can I set a minimum number of rows to display in a UITableView without changing the data source?

Tags: ios, uitableview

How can I set a minimum number of rows to display in a UITableView without changing the data source ?

In other words I would prefer to not add empty objects to the data array, to display the empty rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintain two arrays and check like this

```
  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {   
    if([yourDataArray count]>3 )

     return [yourDataArray count];
    else
       return [demoArray count];
 }
```

here u have to maintain another array, whenever the data Array is less than 3 use demoArray
so that the datasource yourDataArray is left undisturbed

Follow the same for below method also

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
          (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score 0):

In your *tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:* data source method, you may return few more number of rows. The following code assuming your data source is an array.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{   
    int amountOfEmptyRows = 3;
    return [yourDataArray count] + amountOfEmptyRows;
}
```

But make sure that you are not accessing the array index out of bounds because in this case the other table view delegate and data source method will ask for indexPath.row that is beyond your data array length.

Answer (score 0):

What you didn't specify are exactly WHERE the "empty" cells are - at the end of the array or mixed in with "full" cells. Assuming your dataSource is telling the table you want 100 cells displayed, but the data backing those is missing random bits of data, my suggestion would be to set the height of the "empty" cells to zero, and as that data comes in your can reload just the cells that now have data.